# Shortcut to run code via integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently `Ctrl`+`Enter` runs code from the main directory.
I want to change this shortcut to run code from the integrated terminal directly.

My current workflow is:

- right click `file.py`
- Open in integrated terminal
- type python `file.py`

Is there way to change the shortcut above to use the workflow instead.

Comment: why not use launch configs, `F5` and `Ctrl+F5`

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can make a task and assign a keybinding to it.

---

If you don't have a `tasks.json` file, go to the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> if that hasn't been remapped), and enter `Tasks: Configure Tasks`, `Configure tasks.json file from template`, and `Others`. You should now have a `tasks.json` file.

The `tasks` key is an array, and you can insert an object there. For your case, you can have

```json
{
    "label": "Run python file",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "py",
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": false
    }
}
```

To have the keybinding, go to Keyboard Shortcuts (Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> if this hasn't been remapped]) and click `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`.

There, define your own keybinding. For now, I choose <kbd>F5</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>, and we'll add this object.

```json
{
    "key": "f5 f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "when": "editorLangId == python",
    "args": "Run python file"
}
```

To explain, when we press <kbd>F5</kbd> followed by <kbd>F5</kbd> and we are an editor identified as a Python file, VSCode will run the command `workbench.action.tasks.runTask`. To choose which task VSCode will run, we'll provide the name of the task through the `args` key which is `Run python file`.